# Tracking down the "unbalanced" in a design

Tags: r

I have some data from an experiment that should be balanced, but when I try

```
print(model.tables(aov.PDD,"means"),digits=3)
```

I get

```
Error in model.tables.aovlist(aov.PDD, "means") : 
  design is unbalanced so cannot proceed
```

I suspect this means that the coding or entry of the data was incorrect somewhere, but I'd like to be able to track this to more detail before wading into the data frame itself.  How can I get more detail on what factor is producing the unbalance here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The balance in aov refers to the number of observations per cell (combination of all factors).  There are certain formulas that require balance (all the numbers are the same) and therefore give errors when there is not balance.  Sometimes you don't need exactly the same numbers in all cells, but equal withing blocks of cells.  You can just use the `table` function to count how many observations you have per cell.

Generally the parts that require balance are when you start having nested random effects, in this case it is probably better to use a mixed effects model (package nlme or lme4) which uses different techniques and does not require tha balance.

Comment: Thanks Greg!  I understand what balance means; the problem here is that according to the design, it really should be balanced, so there's a problem in the data that needs tracing.  That's my first priority, not adjusting the analysis to unbalanced data.

Comment: @Krysta, and what does `table` tell you about the number of observations in each cell?  If you can provide the data and the actual command used (or simulated data that shows the same error) then it will be easier for us to help.

Comment: Several problems! Working on now.  Thanks for your help, I am an enormonoob to R so much appreciated.